# Time text variable to numeric

Tags: r

I have the following variable which I want to convert to minutes and so get a numeric variable.

For now I am doing the following:

```
require(lubridate)
time <- c("1 hour 10 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "12 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "1 hour 4 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "1 hour 5 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "34 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "50 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 34 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "43 mins", "1 hour 20 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 30 mins", "1 hour 0 mins")

minute(strptime(time,'%M'))
```

In cases like "50 mins" it converts perfect but in cases like "1 hour 0 mins" it converts to 1 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option (similar logic but different approach):

```
library(lubridate)

x[!grepl("hour", x)] <- paste("0 hour", x[!grepl('hour', x)], sep = " ")
hour(strptime(x, "%H hour %M mins"))*60 + minute(strptime(x, "%H hour %M mins"))
# [1] 70 60 12 60
```

**Data**:

```
c("1 hour 10 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "0 hour 12 mins", "1 hour 0 mins"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require(lubridate)
time <- c("1 hour 10 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "12 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "1 hour 4 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "1 hour 5 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "34 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "50 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 34 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "43 mins", "1 hour 20 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
           "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 30 mins", "1 hour 0 mins")
time <- gsub(" mins", "", time)
tmp  <- grepl(" hour ", time)
time <- gsub("1 hour ", "", time) # If you sometimes have > 1 hour then use grep or regexpr here, or more gsubs if you want
time <- as.numeric(time)
time[tmp] <- time[tmp]+60

x <- ymd("1900-01-01") # or whenever

minute(x) <- time

x

 [1] "1900-01-01 01:10:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 00:12:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:04:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"
 [7] "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:05:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 00:34:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"
[13] "1900-01-01 00:50:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"
[19] "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:34:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"
[25] "1900-01-01 00:43:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:20:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "1900-01-01 01:30:00 UTC"
[31] "1900-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"
```

or if you just want the raw number of minutes then of course you already have that in `time`

Answer (score 2):

Here a way to do it:

```
library(chron)

times <- c("1 hour 10 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "12 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
"1 hour 4 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
"1 hour 5 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "34 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
"50 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
"1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
"1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 34 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
"43 mins", "1 hour 20 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 0 mins", 
"1 hour 0 mins", "1 hour 30 mins", "1 hour 0 mins")

# Add "0 hour" when only minutes are present
times <- sub(pattern = "^(\\d+ mins)",replacement = "0 hour \\1", times)

# Change format simply to ease next step
times <- sub(pattern = "^(\\d+) hours? (\\d+) mins", replacement = "\\1\\:\\2", times)

# Convert to a real time vector
times.2 <- strptime(x = times, format = "%H:%M")

# Extract number of minutes
minutes <- 60*hours(times.2) + minutes(times.2)
```

### Results

```
> minutes
 [1] 70 60 12 60 64 60 60 60 65 60 34 60 50 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 94
[24] 60 43 80 60 60 60 90 60
```

Comment: Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: Hmm maybe try restarting your R session... I didn't get any error here.... at what step did you get this error message?